# How to access Cloud Platform for a Google Apps Script when the link is missing

Tags: google-apps-script

[Normally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53992955/how-do-i-send-the-standard-invitation-email-when-calling-addguest-on-a-calendare/55509409#55509409) when I go to Resources > Cloud Platform project... in Google Apps Scripting, I see it says `This script is currently associated with project:` and I have a direct link to the cloud project associated with this script.

However, for some of my scripts, I see the following:

> [image]
>
> This script has an Apps Script-managed Cloud Platform project.

This is problematic because when I try to enable the Advanced Calendar API, for example, I don't know where to find my Cloud Platform project.

Normally I would click that link and then enable the Google Calendar API in the dashboard, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out if you see `This script has an Apps Script-managed Cloud Platform project.` the set up for advanced services is actually much easier.

Simply go to Resources > Advanced Google Services... and enable the one you want. No need to muck around with the Cloud Platform settings!